# Incorrect Timestamp Value - c.getTimeInMills()

Tags: java, android, timestamp

I have a DatePicker which is working correctly, however, when I convert the date to a timestamp, the timestamp is completely wrong.
Please see my code below:

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR); // current year
                int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH); // current month
                int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); // current day
                timestamp = c.getTimeInMillis();
```

The part `c.getTimeInMillis` does not seem to be getting the correct date. Does anyone know how to fix this?

**Edit:** Expected date was today’s date and I'm getting **5/31/51128, 4:47:42 PM**. I have figured out why it is showing the wrong date: the generated timestamp has 3 extra digits at the end. I don't know why though, or how to fix this.

Comment: Please provide the given output and the expected output.

Comment: Have you forgot to set `c` to the date from the date picker? Or did you want a timestamp in seconds and got one in milliseconds? Just guessing.

Comment: Expected date was todays date and I'm getting 5/31/51128, 4:47:42 PM

Comment: I have figured out why it is showing the wrong date: the generated timestamp has 3 extra digits at the end. I don't know why though, or how to fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you are feeding `timestamp`, which is in milliseconds, to a routine that wants seconds.  Those "3 extra digits" are the milliseconds part of the timestamp.  If this sounds right to you, divide `timestamp` by 1000 before passing it on.

Comment: That is wrong you will only delete de last digits at the current timestamp and this is no the intention

Comment: Ok thats great!

Answer (score 0):

I Think you want to get the current milliseconds and for that the instruction will be: `c.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND)`

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR); // current year
    int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH); // current month
    int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); // current day
    int mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR); // current hour
    int mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE); // current min
    int mMilisecond = c.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND); // current milisecond

    System.out.println("Year: "+mYear+", Month: "+mMonth+", Day:"+mDay+", Hour: "+mHour+", mMinute: "+mMinute+", mMilisecond: "+mMilisecond);
}
```

Now the method `getTimeInMillis` like the java documentation saids:

```
/**
 * Returns this Calendar's time value in milliseconds.
 *
 * @return the current time as UTC milliseconds from the epoch.
 * @see #getTime()
 * @see #setTimeInMillis(long)
 */
```

An the epoch is a an absolute time reference