# convert millis to ZonedDateTime not working

Tags: java, epoch, milliseconds, zoneddatetime, date

I have this millis in long:

```
1570046362841
```

when converting with **version 1**:

```
var myDate = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochSecond(1570046362841), ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
```

I will get this result (which is wrong!):

```
+51722-10-16T03:58:54-04:00[America/New_York]
```

However, when converting with **version 2**:

```
 final String dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss SSS";
 SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
 formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
 var dateObj = new Date(1570046362841);
 var myDate = formatter.format(dateObj);
```

I get the correct result:

```
2019-10-02 15:59:59 934
```

**Why is version 1 wrong? What is wrong in version 1?**

Comment: @OleV.V. Wondering why you mark this as duplicate as the only similar thing with the question linked is the problem. Different approach. Different code provided and everything.  Different reproduce procedure.

Comment: Related: [Incorrect Timestamp Value - c.getTimeInMills()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54911688/incorrect-timestamp-value-c-gettimeinmills). @MichaelMichailidis is correct that it is not an exact duplicate, and he sums up the similarity and differences very well. Thanks, Michael.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `Instant.ofEpochSecond()` you need to use `Instant.ofEpochMilli()` because you have millis.