# What does the last number in date -r correspond to?

Tags: linux, macos, date, datetime, time

I am trying to figure out what the last value of running `date -r` on my mac correspond to.  For example,

```
➜  ~ date -r 1615828584730
Fri Jul 27 10:32:10 PDT 53173
```

What does the five digit `53173` in this string mean?

Comment: That's the year. `date` expects a number of seconds and you appear to be giving it milliseconds. Instead of 50 years from 1970, it's 50,000 years.

Comment: Apparently similar: [Incorrect Timestamp Value - c.getTimeInMills()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54911688/incorrect-timestamp-value-c-gettimeinmills)